# VBA. Replace method replaces out of specified range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Dim wsData as Worksheet
Dim ctryToTex As Range

Set wsData = ActiveSheet
Set ctryToTex = wsData.Columns("A")

With ctryToTex
    .Replace What:="01", Replacement:="UK", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="03", Replacement:="Norway", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="04", Replacement:="Sweden", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="05", Replacement:="Finland", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="06", Replacement:="Denmark", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="09", Replacement:="Germany", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="11", Replacement:="Switzerland", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="12", Replacement:="Netherlands", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="13", Replacement:="Belgium", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="16", Replacement:="Italy", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="17", Replacement:="Spain", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="21", Replacement:="France", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
End With
```

I want it to replace numbers with countries in column "A", but instead the macro replaces all found values within the worksheet.

Comment: Your code works as expected (only column A) for me.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Do you have any paste links? For example if in cell B1 you have the formula =A1, then when A1 changes B1 will change also... is that kind of situation happening?

Comment: Please insure you have no merged cells spanning column **A**

Comment: @David, no, I don't have these links. Looks like my excel was overloaded or something. Not it works without any issues.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, thank you for hint, but I didn't have column **A** "expanded". Looks like my excel was overloaded or something. Not it works without any issues.

Comment: Did you previously run a Find operation that looked at the whole workbook rather than a particular sheet? That would cause your problem.

Comment: @rory, maybe I used it not in the VBA but in Excel itself.. I didn't know it could affect my macro

Comment: Yes, they affect each other. Safest bet is to run an irrelevant Find operation in your code before you run the Replace. That should reset it to work at Sheet level.

Comment: @Rory, you are right, that was the problem. I couldn't find how to limit `Find` operation to one Sheet. May you please advice?

Comment: Just run any Find operation and that should reset it.